# Custom Category Page Template

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to style a category template that is based on the twenty twelve category.php template.

I believe i have amended the below to suit, however it is only displaying the header and no content, am i missing a line?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php
                    printf( __( 'Category Archives: %s', 'D-Theme' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
                ?></h1>

                <?php
                    $category_description = category_description();
                    if ( ! empty( $category_description ) )
                        echo apply_filters( 'category_archive_meta', '<div class="category-archive-meta">' . $category_description . '</div>' );
                ?>
            </header>


            <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>


        <?php else : ?>

            <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'D-Theme' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'D-Theme' ); ?></p>
                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </article><!-- #post-0 -->

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->
```

Help is appreciated as always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought i would contribute my answer to the above. I have coded this to display my categories with a date, the person who posted it and a time it was posted, with a main title to display the title of the category in question.

Please see code and screenshot of what this produces, i hope this proves useful :)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="maincontentwrap" role="main">
<h1 class="page-title"><?php
printf( __( 'Category Archives: %s', 'D-Theme' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
                ?></h1>
<div class="pagedivider"></div>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
Written by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?> in <?php the_category(); ?> at <?php the_time('H:h a'); ?> 
<div class="pagedivider"></div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the post content, you would need to use `the_content()` in your wordpress loop. 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Comment: Hi Kenny would this also apply to calling posts in a category? Thanks for the response

Comment: to do that, you would need to retrieve posts from that category, then use the above in your while loop. this should help: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Exclude_Posts_From_Some_Category in the example code where it says: query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-3,-8'), just change the "-3,-8" to the category id you want to use.

Comment: Hi Kenny, thanks for this info. I will have to have a further read. As im not specifically wanting it from one category. I just want one page to display whatever category when it is clicked through, if this makes sense :)